# Access Java class defined in a file with many classes from Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, oop

I have a package which contains a public Kotlin class and a Java file with many package-private top-level classes like so:

```
com.example.mypackage
- KotlinClass.kt
- JavaClasses.java
-- Class1
-- Class2
-- ...
```

If I try to access any class from `JavaClasses` in `KotlinClass` I get `Unresolved reference` error. Is it possible to access these classes?

I cannot change `JavaClasses.java` because it's generated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to access these classes with the setup that you described, the only time I get a an `Unresolved reference` error is when there are errors within the java file. Perhaps because `JavaClasses.java` is generated it doesn't have the correct `package` declaration at the top of the file, which in your case should be `package com.example.mypackage;`